# how to define routingdatasource for two mysql and oracle?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, spring, hibernate

I want to define a routingdatasource for two different databases: mysql and oracle

I've defined the following config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSourceTarget" class="com.test.common.RoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="com.test.common.DataSourceType">
            <entry key="MY_SQL" value-ref="mySqlDataSource"/>
            <entry key="ORACLE" value-ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver.classname}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${mysql.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${mysql.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${oracle.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${oracle.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.passw}" />
</bean>
```

and now I can define session factory and transaction manager

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But this is doesn't work. I'm getting the

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
```

And in addition I must define the dialect for session. 
But how can I define it depending on the datasourse it is working on?

Comment: Routing datasource is your own class? I'd rather create two session factories and then something that will return you a correct session factory. Mind that once hibernate session is open it holds (it depends on configuration bu usually it does) the connection. What if you do the switch then?

Comment: Yes, you right, RoutingDataSourse is my own class, that implements AbstractRoutingDataSource. I can implement "my" RoutingSessionFactory, the question is what is an order of the operations? I think at first RoutingDataSource for the transactional annotation, and then I can get the correct session factory from the ThreadLocals :-). Thanks